# Display a 1-D array in a VB.NET console application

Tags: vb.net, console-application

how would I get this to display?! im stuck! 
trying to make a 1-D array with the months displayed

```
Module Module1 
  Sub Main() 
    Dim months(12) As String 

    months(0) = "January" 
    months(1) = "February" 
    months(2) = "March" 
    months(3) = "April" 
    months(4) = "May" 
    months(5) = "June" 
    months(6) = "July" 
    months(7) = "August" 
    months(8) = "September" 
    months(9) = "October" 
    months(10) = "November" 
    months(11) = "December" 

    Console.ReadLine() 
  End  Sub 
End Module
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine()`?

Comment: Please provide a bit more information.  Do you want to simply write to the console?

Comment: What do you mean by `display`? There are many possibilities. As HTML text on a web page? In a dialog box in a Winforms app? In a command window as a console app? As choices in a `DropDownList`?

Comment: console app... and just I guess have them display as 1D array on the screen or populate?! im kinda lost on arrays to be honest.. but I did manage to get that much down..

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to write each item in the array to the console.
Firstly you would want to use `Console.WriteLine()` instead of `Console.ReadLine()`

Also assuming you would want each item on a new line you would do something like this.

```
for each month as string in months
Console.WriteLine(month)
next
```

Or if you wanted them all on the one line you could do something like this

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",months))
```

This would place all months in a comma seperated string, but the first parameter string.join accepts is a seperator, so you could use any value such as blank space " "

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",months))`, yes. +1